# Give a newcommand two different names with same behavior

Tags: macros

I sometimes forget what name I used for my new commands, ("Was it `\innerproduct` or `\dotproduct` or `\dp` or `\ip`?") and I'd like to be kind to future me by giving the same command multiple names, with the exact same implementation, without duplicating the code. How can I do this?

Comment: `\let\innerproduct=\ip` (or the converse)?. But perhaps, it would faster to search in your files with your TeX editor based on  significant string you remember having used in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via `\let` you can assign a command the meaning that another command *at the time of performing the `\let`-assignment* has.

For example if you have

```
\newcommand\foo{This is foo.}
\let\bar=\foo
\renewcommand\foo{This isn't foo any more.}
```

, then `\bar` will yield `This is foo.` while `\foo` will yield `This isn't foo any more.`

Be aware that LaTeX in this context provides some pitfalls:

LaTeX commands defined in terms of `\newcommand` that process optional arguments actually are "mechanisms" formed by a user-level-command which checks for the presence of an optional argument and then calls an internal command, hereby either passing the default or , in case it is present, the optional argument.

If you have (with optional arguments):

```
\newcommand\foo[1][default]{This is foo with optional argument: #1.}
\let\bar=\foo
\renewcommand\foo[1][default]{%
   This isn't foo any more but still has an optional argument: #1.%
}
```

, then the trap snaps shut:  `\bar[my non-default]` will yield `This isn't foo any more but still has an optional argument: my non-default.`

Reason:

You have a `\newcommand` for creating a macro with optional argument. Thus  `\foo` is defined to check for the presence of an optional argument and then to call an internal argument whose name is derived from the phrase `\foo`.

The `\let`-assignment assigns `\bar` the meaning of `\foo`, i.e., `\bar` is also defined to check for the presence of an optional argument and then to call an internal argument whose name is derived from the phrase `\foo`.

Besides the command `\foo` that internal command is redefined also by the `\renewcommand\foo...`-assignment and thus `\bar` will call that redefined variant.

Similar problems with commands defined in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand` as these commands check the current definition of the token `\protect` and depending on that call another internal macro.

Thus the package [letltxmacro](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) might be of interest to you.

---

In "nitpicking-mode" one can ask what is meant by "same behavior/same implementation":

Assume a macro which shall print its own name.

This could look like

```
\newcommand\foo{My name is \texttt{\string\foo}}
```

Assume you wish a macro `\bar` which does also print its own name.
In some sense the behavior of `\bar` would be the same as the behavior of `\foo`.

But this can't be done via `\let\bar=\foo` because then `\bar` will definitely not print its own name but will print "My name is `\foo`" while `\foo` is not the name of `\bar`.